# curved style for image

Tags: html, css, web, styles

How to design the curved style for the image in 3d!

The original image has to be show like below image. Because In 3d rotation I need to show it in dynamically like the below image.

For editing in Photoshop for each image has take much time so it need to be manipulate at run time.

[image]

```css
div.img img{
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    height:250px;
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
<img src="http://po-web.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/it-solution1.jpg" alt="Klematis">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you format your post in the form of a question? Regarding the image, is there any reason why you don't want to photoshop the image instead of using CSS?

Comment: At run time I need to change to the curved format. So, that I am not using the Photoshop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get this efect setting multiple divs with the same background image, and arranging them in a curved path along the Z axis.

As an extra, you can get an hover animation

```css
.test {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective: 1200px;
    transition: perspective 2s, transform 2s; 
    margin: 50px;
}

.test:hover {
    perspective: 600px;
    transform: scale(0.85);
}

.element {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/1000/666);
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 800px 600px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}

.element:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateZ(600px) rotateY(calc(7deg * 5)) translateZ(-600px);
}

.element:nth-child(2) {
    transform: translateZ(600px) rotateY(calc(7deg * 4)) translateZ(-600px);
    background-position: 10% 0px;
}

.element:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateZ(600px) rotateY(calc(7deg * 3)) translateZ(-600px);
    background-position: 20% 0px;
}

.element:nth-child(4) {
    transform: translateZ(600px) rotateY(calc(7deg * 2)) translateZ(-600px);
    background-position: 30% 0px;
}

.element:nth-child(5) {
    transform: translateZ(600px) rotateY(calc(7deg)) translateZ(-600px);
    background-position: 40% 0px;
}

.element:nth-child(6) {
    background-position: 50% 0px;
}

.element:nth-child(7) {
    transform: translateZ(600px) rotateY(calc(-7deg)) translateZ(-600px);
    background-position: 60% 0px;
}

.element:nth-child(8) {
    transform: translateZ(600px) rotateY(calc(-7deg * 2)) translateZ(-600px);
    background-position: 70% 0px;
}

.element:nth-child(9) {
    transform: translateZ(600px) rotateY(calc(-7deg * 3)) translateZ(-600px);
    background-position: 80% 0px;
}

.element:nth-child(10) {
    transform: translateZ(600px) rotateY(calc(-7deg * 4)) translateZ(-600px);
    background-position: 90% 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```