# CSS 3D transform a div into a bent arch shape

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, svg

I want to know if is it possible to shape a div like an arch, preferrably with CSS, Jquery and such, but not with flash.
I also want to know if it's going to use too much RAM or CPU and if there isn't a way, if there is a way to make it at least look like it.
Here's an example of what I want:

[image]

I've seen the answers, and I was thinking, how would that be done with HTML5 Canvas? Also, maybe could it be done with code-generated SVG?

Comment: You could do something like that with big white circles and z-index, but the  content of the div would stay untouched. You need html5 canvas to get what you want exactly.

Comment: I recently answered something similar. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30817828/1926369

Comment: @vals that is pure voodoo and deserves an upvote.

Comment: Html/css/js fail here and lots of other places which are too beyond the word document.

Comment: The easiest solution would probably be to shuffle pixels around on a Canvas.  It could be done on SVG by warping all the coords in the SVG, but that would be harder than the Canvas method.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/e8hZy/

Answer (score 3):

You can use divs with border radius and reveal them when you want the arch shape to happen using JQuery. Look at my jsfiddle for an example : http://jsfiddle.net/ECHWb/530/ Click on the div to make it an arch.

```
   $('#center').click(function(){
      $('#top').animate({height: "50px"});
      $('#bottom').animate({height: "50px"});
   });
```

Answer (score 3):

Using CSS? no.. can't be done (yet)  CSS just allows linear transformations (skew, scale, rotate)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to achieve that result with **multiple divs side by side** and placed the good way...

I'm working with that to make a 360 view panorama to seem realistic 3D.

Unfortunately i can not provide a demo for now...
but that can be the best approach to obtain a real 3d feeling.